# Tray Notification when there is new RSS

Tags: c#, rss-reader

So i am working on a Windows Form application that grabs Rss and displays it in Treeview. So Far everything is working, So my question is how would i display a notification when there is new Rss. e.g (if there is new rss, notifyicon control should notify user and show them info about that new feed). Code below shows how i am grabbing RSS

```
 public void MainRss()
    {
        try
        {
            //WFTvw is Treeview Name
            // create a new xml doc
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

            try
            {
                // load the xml doc
                doc.Load(RssUrl);


            }
            catch (Exception ex1)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(ex1.Message);
                return;
            }

            // get an xpath navigator   
            XPathNavigator navigator = doc.CreateNavigator();

            try
            {
                // look for the path to the rss item titles; navigate
                // through the nodes to get all titles
                XPathNodeIterator nodes = navigator.Select("//rss/channel/item/title");

                while (nodes.MoveNext())
                {
                    // clean up the text for display
                    XPathNavigator node = nodes.Current;

                    string dspRss = node.Value.Trim();


                    dspRss = dspRss.Replace("\n", "");
                    dspRss = dspRss.Replace("\r", "");



                    // add a new treeview node for this
                    // news item title
                    WFTvw.Nodes.Add(tmp);  
                }


                // set a position counter
                int position = 0;

                // Get the links from the RSS feed
          XPathNodeIterator nodesLink = navigator.Select("//rss/channel/item/author");

                while (nodesLink.MoveNext())
                {
                    // clean up the link
                    XPathNavigator node = nodesLink.Current;
                    string dspRss2 = node.Value.Trim();
                    dspRss2 = dspRss2.Replace("\n", "");
                    dspRss2 = dspRss2.Replace("\r", "");
                    // clean up the link


                    // use the position counter
                    // to add a link child node
                    // to each news item title
                    WFTvw.Nodes[position].Nodes.Add(dspRss2);

                    // increment the position counter
                    position++;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "RSS Feed Load Error");
            }

            // restore the cursor
            this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
           WFTvw.ExpandAll();

        }
        catch (Exception ex2)
        {
            // snitch
            MessageBox.Show(ex2.ToString(), "RSS Feed Initialization Failure");
        }
    }
```

and below is how i am updating my rss

```
public void refreshRssTimer()
    {
        var timer = new Timer();
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(refreshTimer_Tick);
        timer.Interval = 60000; //60 seconds
        timer.Start();
    }
```

and timer tick

```
 private void refreshTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WFTvw.Nodes.Clear();
        MainRss();

    }
```

Comment: your code will refresh RSS list in your `Treeview` completely every 1 minute, how do you want to detect if there is new RSS should be your first question.

Comment: For showing systray icon see http://alperguc.blogspot.de/2008/11/c-system-tray-minimize-to-tray-with.html

Comment: @Bolu so how would i go about refreshing the rss feed when there is new one, because right now without tick_timer, i can't get new rss feed.

Comment: that's fine for loading new RSS, but you have to find out a way to identify when there is something new in the feed. e.g. compare newly loaded one with the previous list. And if you don't know how, then like I already suggested in my previous comments, this should be your question to ask.